For what integers does this inequality hold true?
For what integers $a_{j},b_{j}\geq 2$, $j=1,\dots,n$, is the following inequality true:
$$\min\left\{\min_{1\leq j\leq n}{\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}},
\min_{1\leq j\leq n}{\frac{b_{j}}{a_{j}}}\right\}\leq \min_{1\leq k \leq n} \frac{\sum_{j\neq k}\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}}{n-1+\frac{1}{b_{k}}\min_{j\neq k}\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}}.\tag{*}$$
The stronger inequality
$$\min_{1\leq j\leq n}{\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}}\leq \min_{1\leq k \leq n} \frac{\sum_{j\neq k}\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}}{n-1+\frac{1}{b_{k}}\min_{j\neq k}\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}}.\tag{**}$$
seems to hold whenever
$$\left|\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}-\frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}}\right|>\delta,\quad j\neq k,$$ for some $\delta=\delta(n,a_{1},b_{1},\dots,a_{n},b_{n})>0$. Notice that when $\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}=C$ the converse of $(**)$ holds. So, one can find a small enough $\delta$ such that the converse of $(**)$ holds whenever when $\left|\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}-\frac{a_{k}}{b_{k}}\right|\leq \delta$, for all $j\neq k$. By a similar argument $(*)$ seems to be true when $\frac{a_{j}}{b_{j}}$ is large enough. Can we make this precise ?
